# retrieving the id of the view that was clicked

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm using `MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{`

This activity references around 10+ buttons and has `setOnClicklistener(this)` method called on every button.

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v){
    //here I need to get the id of the view that was clicked...
    //Depending on the button that was clicked different actions need to be called...
    //How do I get the ID of the button that was clicked...
}
```

Comment: Why not google it first? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()

Comment: You're given the View object that was clicked... seriously this question had to be asked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v){
switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btnCancel:
        //your code for onclick of that button
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following method to get id.

```
v.getId()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Override 
    public void onClick(View v){
        int id = v.getId();
        if(id == R.id.button_ok){

         }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `View` parameter that is sent to your `onClick` method is the actual button that was clicked, therefore you can check which one it is, for example:

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1: ...; break;
        case R.id.button_2: ...; break;
        case R.id.button_3: ...; break;
        ...
        default: //unknown button clicked
    }
}
```

This is only one option, there are other.  Search google for more info.

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
if(v.getId()==R.id.whatever)
{
// do something
}
```

or you can even use :
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

```
if(v==btn)
{
// do something
}
```

but the second one is not recommended.