# How can we get the id of the view that was touched in onTouchListener in Android when the user is moving the finger on the views?

Tags: android, view, ontouchlistener, motionevent, ontouch

I am not able to get the second view id where the finger is moved. I tried to print the id where the pointer is using the following in the on touch listener.

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++) {
                //System.out.println(v.getId());
                System.out.println(event.getX() + "---" + event.getY());
                System.out.println(v.getId());
            }
            break;
```

Here event is my MotionEvent and v is the View. I am able to get the X and Y positions of the touch, but i want to know which view is being crossed. I get only the view id of the first view that was pressed all the time.

I have checked the following links for some help, but was unable to get any relevant details.

[How do I get the ID of the moving finger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161920/how-do-i-get-the-id-of-the-moving-finger)

[retrieving the id of the view that was clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316359/retrieving-the-id-of-the-view-that-was-clicked)

[how to get the particular sub view id from the view in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841914/how-to-get-the-particular-sub-view-id-from-the-view-in-android)

Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a listener on a view you'll always get that view inside the event. For example

```
View one = findById(R.id.one);
one.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
      // v == one
  }
})
```

But if you declare your Activity as the touch listener:

```
Activity implements OnTouchListener
```

Then you set the listener on the root view:

```
View rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);
rootView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

And override onTouch:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) { 
    // here v is what you look for
}
```

I think you should check if you're setting onTouchListener on root view and not one particular view

Comment: Hey @Javier, I tried that, but didn't help. I have a relative layout and inside which i have a few image buttons which overlap each other. When i press a button, i can detect the touch. But the problem is with dragging the finger to the second button, as soon as i touch the other button to which i move, i cannot detect the second view, the id that i get is still of the first view.

Comment: Could you post how you are setting the touch listener?

Comment: I have implemented the listener as follows :

`public class MyClass implements OnTouchListener, OnLongClickListener {}

 @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     //Here I have used switch case to identify the id of the button that was pressed

}
`

Comment: Ok, but how are you setting the touch listener? something like `View rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);
rootView.setOnTouchListener(this);`